# Code font size of the new layout looks smaller than it was in web browser

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, code-formatting

I just found out that Stack Overflow has a new outfit. I don't want to bother with the aesthetic part but I do care about the font size of the code block:

I'll use [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) to demonstrate the difference, comparing it with a [February 2013 version from the Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130223115801/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array). (Try tabbing back and forth between those two and seeing for yourself!)

### Before

> The regular text font size is 13.7px, and so is the code font size. (1:1)
>
> [image]
>
> (from [February 2013 via the Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130223115801/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array))

### After

> The regular text font size is now 15px, and the font size is 12px. (So the regular text has gotten bigger, and the code smaller.)
>
> [image]
>
> (from [the current version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array))

---

The new layout makes the code **look even smaller** with the enlarged text font size, and it becomes really clear when looking back and forth between regular text and code. I am wondering if SE has any plan to enlarge the code font size as well.

P.S. Results are the same in the web browsers **Firefox** and **IE**, both of the latest version.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit this question with what may be a more effective demonstration & comparison, and add a little more info about the difference?

Comment: @doppelgreener Please do, I will be very appreciate of your edit. I am not a native English speaker and there are much more I'd like to say about the font.

Comment: Agreed, Jin's upping the font size a bit in the next build coming in just a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the @doppelgreener 's effort. He really makes this issue much more clear.

Comment: It looks like the font sizing is somehow inverted in the whole design. Close voting dialog is [now shouting](http://i.imgur.com/JceFiEE.png) on people. The [old font setting](http://i.imgur.com/cuNIoK1.png) was perfectly decent.

Comment: A theme switch option that allows user to set what suits them the best would sure be nice!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283667/should-the-new-font-size-be-larger-by-default

Comment: @charlietfl: A theme switch function means multiplying the UI efforts because all UI development have to be checked against all themes.

Comment: Just my 2cents: I find it harder to read. Why always tinker..?

Comment: I might have missed it but is there a reason (as in usability improvement) for the change of design stated somewhere? (I'm interested in the logic behind because I think it impacts my SO experience in a negative way right now, without intention of being disrespectful).

Comment: **I like it.** The code is easier to glance over while reading over the question. It especially helps when an asker posts a wall of code or many snippets. Having the smaller font size makes the question seem less overwhelming and nicer to organize visually. Plus the more (in my opinion) important parts of the question (the user's descriptions) are better emphasized. I'm no UX expert but it's just my .02.

Comment: @MatthieuM In these days of  dynamic stylesheet languages like `less` and `sass` it is reasonably trivial to set up alternative themes that have no impact on UI functionality. The suggestion wasn't for complete layout changes, just styles.

Comment: @charlietfl: it's not a matter of functionality, but one of display. You have to check that in each style that the text does not overflow, that the boxes do not overlap, etc... If you restrict yourself to changing the colors, it just works, but if you can customize font, etc... then suddenly you are at risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I shrank the code block font size was so you have more visible content upfront so less vertical or horizontal scrolling. However, I do agree the initial 12px was a bit too small. I have since upped it to 13px. The change should be on live now.

Comment: Thank you. Daily small code font size could be detrimental to an software engineer's eyes!

Comment: Please can we get it to 14? I was about to write the question and I got this one in the suggestions so I don't want to duplicate, but am requesting you to make it 14px as it looks appropriate.