# Should the new font size be larger by default?

Tags: feature-request, design

I have noticed that there seems to be a new design on the stackoverflow site.

The font is now smaller than I was used to, so this is the point I guess to notice it. Anyhow, I am a 28 years old person who does not need glasses and uses a normal 100% view on the screen for text, icons etc.

But I do find it a bit small - so I wonder if anybody else is having issues and we should think about setting the font size larger? I don't want to use a zoom setting on a browser as this would also be rolled out to other sites in a browser session.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Interestingly, the font size in the answers' and comments' edit boxes suffers from the opposite problem - it's too big and needs really be made back smaller.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283613/

Comment: Agree, reduced readability. Had to scale up the font on the front page.

Comment: Personally, I like it.

Comment: It's not only smaller, it's also lighter. The question titles on the homepage aren't bold anymore

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That together with the smaller font size is the main issues I see right now that affect my experience of SO in a negative way compared to before.

Comment: I don't know about your browser, but Firefox remembers the zoom level per domain.

Comment: Yeah it is too small now, for a standard 1900x1200 monitor... Yet another pointless/harmful change to SO. "If it ain't broken, it ain't got enough features yet!"

Comment: +1 for using the "ask question" button to ask a rhetorical question.

Comment: It is a nice font, but harder to read: it appears smaller and lower contrast.  I have zoomed my SO windows to 110%, which is not a great solution b/c some things on the page don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the font-size has been **increased** from

```
font-size: 13.7px;
line-height: 130%; (17.81px)
```

to

```
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1.3; (19.5px)
```

Only the [code font size is smaller now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283613/1048572).

Comment: `seems` != `is`

Comment: @Deduplicator: That's true. Probably due to the increased spacing around the texts. Maybe we should change *that* back?

Comment: @Bergi, I agree, text feels a bit lost to me ATM.

Comment: Everything is smaller.  More text that's harder to read.  Not an improvement imho.

Comment: This is very interesting. I believe what you say - and I do not know if it is more spacing or any other effects - but for me it is really harder to read and needs more concentration and effort. It makes me really tired currently

Comment: @Stefan I tried to take a comparison screenshot when the design was first being tested, but it turned out the fonts were about the same size vertically.  I think the issue is more the new styling makes it _seem_ smaller, so I have to squint when visiting SO now.