# Font in the editor is too large

Tags: bug, design, editor

I really like that [code blocks have a smaller font size now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283613/1048572), which makes now 90 characters per line available instead of only 81 - I've often went for the maximum when carefully word-wrapping comments so that there was no horizontal overflow.

On the contrary, the font size in the editor textarea had been increased (when it changed to a non-monospace font, which was OK); and has not been decreased again when [we got Courier back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283645/1048572).

Compare the old editor:
[image: old editor, with two lines of code block that exhaust the 81 available characters of the old column width]

to the new design:
[image: new editor, with code blocks lines that overflow in the editor at 81 characters and even more with the newly available 90]

Even the old code blocks (85 characters width in the editor) do now overflow the editor size, and are soft-wrapped in new lines; which looks really ugly.
**Please decrease the font size** so that 94 characters fit in a single editor line.

Comment: +6/-4 seems quite controverse. Please formulate an answer to share your opinions!