# Default edit box too small

Tags: feature-request, design, editor, user-experience

The editor has by default 9 rows.

Almost every time I edit or write a post I catch myself resizing the editor box to make it bigger. Especially for code segments it is annoying to have such a small editor.

Can it be larger by default?

Comment: This is especially annoying with the comparatively *huge* editor font-size.

Comment: Chrome can manually resize that box. I also didnt like the small size but I don't had to live with it in Chrome

Comment: @Matt: I know I can resize it with the mouse. Or do you have a method of changing the **default** height in Chrome?

Comment: @J.Steen: See [Font in the editor is too large](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284105/1048572) for that

Answer (score 46):

You are right, on most monitors the box is too small for comfort.

However, I'm not in favor of giving it a fixed bigger size: That would be problematic with smaller devices like small tablets.

Instead, I think a starting size that's relative to the window size would be appropriate. A good compromise could be to use roughly half the height of the browser window for the input box, which leaves the other half for the preview. I find myself frequently checking that preview to check whether syntax highlighting and formatting is right and would like to avoid scrolling between the input and the preview as much as possible.

Comment: responsive design :)

Comment: It's a good idea, but apparently [window-size-based sizing just isn't done here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283902).

Comment: One could increase the height of the box once when it obtains keyboard focus (with an animation explaining what is happening).

Comment: That would make it smaller on my tiny laptop, but It would help with my problem of constantly scrolling to change whether I'm looking at the editor or preview.

Comment: you'd think they would have done this years ago and it would have been a top priority for usability

Answer (score 10):

*(**Note**: The browser extension mentioned is no longer available for use in the current versions of the Firefox browser).*

You're right, it's pretty small for a lot of answers. To workaround this I use an add-on for Firefox browser I mainly use called [*It's All Text*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/?src=ss) which briefly places a small <kbd>Edit</kbd> button in the lower right corner of all edit boxes on any web pages I view.

If I click the button, it copies the current contents of the edit page into a new temporary file and invokes my favorite text editor on it. Any changes I make are automatically sent back to the browser edit box whenever I save them (often just before or as I quit the editor) where I can view the results. This is really nice for code, because my editor has a number special features designed specifically for a number of languages, such as syntax highlighting and code folding, all of which are available to me.

Here's its preference dialog:

[image: screenshot of its all text preference dialog box]

There may be something similar for whatever browser you're using, which sounds like it might be Chrome.

Comment: The link is broken (due to Firefox Quantum?) - *"Oops! We can’t find that page"*.

Comment: @Peter: Indeed, the linked Firefox extension isn't compatible with current versions of the browser and has been discontinued because of security restrictions that have been imposed. Nowadays I use some custom AutoHotkey macros I wrote that copy the editbox's text and paste it into my favorite text editor (and when I'm done I just manually copy & paste it back into the browser's editbox). So much for progress…

Comment: Found two alternatives, but both of them require an external, native backend to deal with stuff. [Linux-only](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textern/) (Python 3.5 + Linux, Firefox only), [cross-platform](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/withexeditor/) (Node.JS 10.0.0 or newer, cross-platform and supports several browsers, admittedly some with varying platform support. The Firefox port supports Windoze, Mac, and Linux). Disclaimer: I don't use either of these, nor have I tried to.

Comment: why should we "work around / hack" Stack's major usability issues and their stubbornness to improve.  Also not everyone uses Windows

Answer (score -1):

I wrote [a userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Three-Columns) for those with reasonably wide screens which makes the textarea take up the whole vertical height of the browser in a column, and puts the preview in a column next to it, and rest of the original page in a third column. It makes typing and proofing non-trivial answers *much* easier. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

More details on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/8525)