# More responsive text editor and fixed-position code editor. Wait for the changes to arrive or publish a browser extension myself?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think StackOverflow should improve the usability of their sites to make the user's experience better and to make easier and more pleasant for us to use the site, and there are some aspects that are very easy to correct.

For example, I find very annoying that when I'm writing a code snippet and I need to scroll any of the 4 different areas on the popup, if I scroll to the end, intended or not, the whole page scrolls, including the popup (which I think should stay in place).

This can be fixed just changing a `position: absolute` for a `position: fixed` and some other position properties.

As I was thinking about this, I found a similar question complaining about the scrolling of the answer/question editor:

[Proposed improvements to scrolling in the editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289191/proposed-improvements-to-scrolling-in-the-editor)

...which can be very annoying too as you have to be continuously scrolling up and down to see the preview of your answer.

The point of my question is that **I did a crappy Chrome extension to fix that** some time ago and now I was going to fix the code snippet editor too, but as I see that I'm not the only one having trouble with this kind of stuff, **do you think it is a good idea to improve the extension a bit and publish it on the Chrome Store** (for now it’s just on my computer)?

[image]

I think the best solution would be that the StackOverflow team corrected that in the page itself, but if that takes too long this may be a good alternative. However, if changes are made frequently in the page it may become a pain to have to be constantly updating the extension to keep it working if it begins to add more and more fixes for different things. If you do a quick search here you can see that there are a lot of things that could be improved.

So far I’ve edited it just a couple of times, but it was not completely broken, just noticed some portions of the page where not in place. There are some others that still need to be fixed. For example, I've only created a question once some time ago (this would be my second), so I didn't notice that in the `/ask` page the extension is also working but some content of the column on the right is overlapping the preview:

[image]

So, what would you do? Do you like the idea of the extension?

**EDIT:**

Just in case someone wants to know about the extension, it is already published. You can download it from the Chrome Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-steroids/hmpehldkjbnpdhebfangeaoabhphihic

And make contributions in GitHub:

https://github.com/Danziger/StackOverflow-Steroids

If you want to request new features use the built-in Chrome Store support system or check this other question:

[Chrome extension as a way to introduce (and test) new features faster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302600/chrome-extension-as-a-way-to-introduce-and-test-new-features-faster)

Comment: "Do you like the idea of the extension?" **Yes**. If you opensource it, I can help you, as I have loads of time. Might be able to port it to Firefox / Greasemonkey too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had been really busy and I completely forgot about this... Finally, here they are, the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-steroids/hmpehldkjbnpdhebfangeaoabhphihic and the repo: https://github.com/Danziger/StackOverflow-Steroids. Contributions are welcomed! I will finish the `README` in a moment!