# Chrome extension as a way to introduce (and test) new features faster

Tags: discussion

A few months ago I came up with a few posts/questions here complaining about the bad usability that StackExchange sites, in general, have.

I created a question suggesting the possibility of fixing them using a Chrome Extension instead of just commenting them here, but it did not attract much attention:

[More responsive text editor and fixed-position code editor. Wait for the changes to arrive or publish a browser extension myself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295609/more-responsive-text-editor-and-fixed-position-code-editor-wait-for-the-changes)

After a long time, I have finally added a few extra features and improvements in general to make it more attractive for other people to install it (previously it was just an anemic extension that injected a few lines of messy `CSS`).

You can download it (or just check its current features) from the Chrome Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-steroids/hmpehldkjbnpdhebfangeaoabhphihic

From the Chrome Store:

> It's main features are:
>
> 1. New design for the top navigation bar that keeps visible as many elements as possible, even in narrow windows, and fixes it at the top
>      of the page.
> 2. Side-to-side editor (if window is wide enough) that makes it easier for you to write long questions or answers without being continuously
>      scrolling up and down to see the preview. It's design has also been
>      tuned a bit.
> 3. Prevent page scrolling when the answer or code editors are focused (when using keys) or the mouse is over them (when using scroll wheel),
>      so that everything is in place while you are working.
> 4. New overlay design for the editor help.

Here you can see a screenshot of the options popup:

[image]

Comments and suggestions are welcomed, as well as contributions. The extension is published at GitHub, so anyone can open a pull request with new features or improvements on the current ones:

https://github.com/Danziger/StackOverflow-Steroids

**I would like to know if someone is missing any important feature that he or she thinks that should be introduced as soon as possible.**

The main improvements made so far are in the editor, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

**NOTE:** This question is duplicated in [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/6537/chrome-extension-as-a-way-to-introduce-and-test-new-features-on-stackoverflow). [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suggested to post this there and it seems a good idea, but I did not know that forum before...

https://stackapps.com/questions/6537/chrome-extension-as-a-way-to-introduce-and-test-new-features-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Why not post this on http://stackapps.com, a site *dedicated* to add-ons for Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that forum... I have just posted it: http://stackapps.com/questions/6537/chrome-extension-as-a-way-to-introduce-and-test-new-features-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Please include some information about what it actually does. The screenshot does not tell me anything about it's features.

Comment: StackExchange has no forum. It has a blogs, chat rooms and a whole bunch of Q&A sites though. And hats... sometimes.

Comment: Why is this limited to "StackOverflow"?

Comment: How does this compare to [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I have edited the post to add a summary of its features.

Comment: @Jamen, in a Chrome extension `manifest` you have to specify in which URL patterns you want to inject your `CSS` and `JS` files.

Previously I had just `*://*.stackoverlow.com/*` and `*://*.stackexchange.com/*`. However, there are some sites, like [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com) that break with the changes of the extension, that's why it's limited to _StackOverflow_. I should probably take some time to test the extension on the main StackExchange sites to see in which ones I can use it too and how I can do that without having too many URL rules.

Comment: @rene, the main difference is that [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) is just for _minor client-side bug fixes, work-arounds and usability improvements_. Just with the few features SO Steroids has so far it is already changing the original design of the site. The second difference is that the `CSS` code is injected directly by SO Steroids, depending on a URL match, while SOUP uses a (big) JS file.

Comment: But both are compatible, right?

Comment: Yes, on StackOverflow they are. On some of the other StackExchange sites SO Steroids will break the layout.

Comment: Nice - this is *similar* to my [SE Additional Optional Features](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) userscript in that it adds *features*! :) I +1'd you on StackApps as well :)