# Expand the editor default height

Tags: feature-request, design, editor

I don't understand why Stack won't expand the editor more. I know we can grab the handle and expand the height of this editor but it's painful...because the default is so short I find myself doing it *every* time I edit a post.

Why not double the default height so that at least we can type half the time without the need to always expand it?

[image]

Comment: See userscript in [answer on the linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399817) for a solution

Comment: All I'm asking is to make the default hight double, which for any resolution would work just fine.  The hight on this default is ridiculous and I have to expand it every damn time no matter what post I'm making.  Doubling it would at least make it enough room so I wouldn't have to always expand it every time.  I might want to expand it but my urge to do so would go down greatly just by defaulting this to a more normal height.  This is a SIMPLE usability tweak that I can't believe stack has ignored.